# How do I retrieve the values of a radio group from an HTML dialog?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dialog, radio-button

index.html:

```
  <body>
    <dialog class="dialog">
      <form class="report__form" method="dialog">
        <div>
          <input type="radio" name="report" vale="vulgar" />
          <label for="vulgar">Vulgar/Offensive Language</label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="radio" name="report" vale="duplicate" />
          <label for="Duplicate">Duplicate</label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="radio" name="report" vale="broken" />
          <label for="broken">Broken</label>
        </div>
        <button class="dialog__submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </dialog>
    <button class="open">open dialog</button>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
```

script.js:

```
const dialog = document.querySelector(".dialog");
const reportForm = document.querySelector(".report__form");
const submitButton = document.querySelector(".dialog__submit");
const openButton = document.querySelector(".open");

openButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  dialog.showModal();
});
```

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to retrieve the radio input values within an HTML dialog. I read the MDN docs on radio inputs but am still struggling to get it to work within the context of a dialog. I figure I need to set a default value, loop through the inputs, and update that value if I click one of them, but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prefer respecting Dialog logic :
use `dialog.returnValue`
because `<dialog>` element can be closed by **Escape key**
which invalidate any form input values

```js
const
  openButton = document.querySelector('.open')
, dialog     = document.querySelector('.dialog')
, reportForm = document.querySelector('.report__form')
  ;
openButton.addEventListener('click',()=>
  {
  reportForm.reset();
  dialog.returnValue = 'none'; // in case of Escape key used... 
  dialog.showModal();          // even if a radio button is checked  
  });
dialog.addEventListener('close',()=> 
  {
  console.clear();
  console.log('dialog.returnValue =', dialog.returnValue);  // here it is !
  }); 
reportForm.addEventListener('submit',()=> 
  { 
  dialog.close(reportForm.report.value); // set dialog.returnValue 
  });                                    // on dialog close event
```

```css
label { display: block; cursor: pointer;}
```

```html
<dialog class="dialog">
  <form class="report__form" method="dialog">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="report" value="vulgar" required >
      Vulgar/Offensive Language
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="report" value="duplicate" >
      Duplicate
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="report" value="broken" >
      Broken
    </label>
    <button class="dialog__submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</dialog>
<button class="open">open dialog</button>
```

Comment: It's very odd to assume that closing a dialog would be considered an 'affirmative action' - especially when there's a submit button to confirm the user's choice.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan What's really strange is rejecting an answer showing correct use of dialog programming cinematics, in order to justify your answer based on circumventing it.

Comment: Thank you this is a good point, the dialog was having weird behavior as it would still store the form information even after closing it and opening another one

Answer (score 3):

Firstly you need to give each checkbox a `value` attribute, not a `vale` attribute. From there you can select the `:checked` element when the form is submit and process it as required.

Also note that the `for` attributes in the `label` elements need to match the `id` of the checkbox. As your checkboxes have no `id`, this is not working. Although you can simplify this by wrapping the checkboxes in the `label` elements, that way you don't need to include the `for` attribute at all.

Here's working example with the above changes made:

```js
const dialog = document.querySelector(".dialog");
const reportForm = document.querySelector(".report__form");
const openButton = document.querySelector(".open");

openButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  dialog.showModal();
});

reportForm.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  const selectedValue = reportForm.querySelector('input[type="radio"]:checked').value;
  console.log(selectedValue);
});
```

```html
<dialog class="dialog">
  <form class="report__form" method="dialog">
    <div>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="report" value="vulgar" />
        Vulgar/Offensive Language
      </label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="report" value="duplicate" />
        Duplicate
      </label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="report" value="broken" />
        Broken
      </label>
    </div>
    <button class="dialog__submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</dialog>
<button class="open">open dialog</button>
```

Comment: in case no submit event is triggered, there is no processing possible when closing the dialog box

Comment: there is no point using a `querySelector()` for a form element

Answer (score 2):

This is based on the MDN documentation.
Explanation- From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData)

> `Form`-  An HTML  element — when specified, the FormData object will be populated with the form's current keys/values using the name property of each element for the keys and their submitted value for the values. It will also encode file input content.

This `FormData` object contains the selected input value under a `key` named after the name value you specified under by `name` in the input, which is, in your case- `name="report"`.

```js
const form = document.querySelector("form");
const openDialog = document.getElementById("opDialog");
const dialog = document.getElementById("dialog1");


opDialog.addEventListener("click", () => {
  dialog.showModal();
  console.clear();
});

form.addEventListener("submit", doThis);

function doThis() {
  let data = new FormData(form);
  for (const entry of data) {
    console.log(entry[1]);
  }
  dialog.close();
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<dialog id="dialog1" class="dialog">
  <form class="report__form" method="dialog">
    <div>
      <input type="radio" name="report" value="vulgar" checked id="reportChoice1" >
      <label for="reportChoice1" >Vulgar/Offensive Language</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="radio" name="report" value="duplicate" id="reportChoice2" >
      <label for="reportChoice2" >Duplicate</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="radio" name="report" value="broken" id="reportChoice3" >
      <label for="reportChoice3" >Broken</label>
    </div>
    <menu>
      <button type="submit" value="confirmBtn">Confirm</button>
    </menu>

  </form>
</dialog>
<button id="opDialog" class="open">open dialog</button>
```